# Dodge Grand Caravan Won't Turn Over

Tags: electrical, dodge, electronic-control-module, no-crank-no-start, grand-caravan

I have a Dodge Grand Caravan 2001 that was having running rough and the exhaust smelled like raw gas. I replaced some sensors and that didn't work so I decided to replace the ECU. I got a new ECU from FlagshipOne and put it in and now the car won't turn over at all. I put the old ECU back in and get the same result. What should I check now?

Also, the battery is not an issue. I charged it up and nothing changed.

Update: I waited a little bit and then tried starting the car again with the old ECU. It started up but still had the rough idle, etc... So I put the new ECU in, waited, but it still will not turn over with the new ECU. I can hear the fuel pump run and I can get the live sensor data with a OBDII tool but it still won't start.

Comment: So, when you put the original ECU back in, does "same result" mean same result as original ECU, or now the original ECU is not allowing it to turn over?  Please [edit] your question to clarify.  Welcome!

Comment: @MarkStewart I've since waited a bit and then tried to start the car again with the old ECU. Then it started. So I put the new ECU and no start. So I waited and tried again but it still won't turn over. Thanks!